# Round off decimals values in all objects of a Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

This is my JSON string

```
[{"$id":"1","GeoName":"EAST","Value2":87.88221970554928,"Value4":90.71955219607294,"Value1":18.44377295716579,"Value3":16.732108234801206},{"$id":"2","GeoName":"WEST","Value2":87.88221970554928,"Value4":90.71955219607294,"Value1":18.44377295716579,"Value3":16.732108234801206}]"
```

This is my JSONobject before Stringyfying

```
**MyObj:**


0:Object
    $id:"1"
    Value1:18.44377295716579
    GeoName:"EAST"
    Value2:87.88221970554928
    Value3:16.732108234801206
    Value4:90.71955219607294
1:Object
    $id:"2"
    Value1:18.44377295716579
    GeoName:"WEST"
    Value2:87.88221970554928
    Value3:16.732108234801206
    Value4:90.71955219607294
```

Is there a way to round off all the values(or even individually value1,value2...) upto 2 decimal points in each every object of my JSON?

Like

```
0:Object
        $id:"1"
        Value1:18.44
        GeoName:"EAST"
        Value2:87.89
        Value3:16.73
        Value4:90.72
1:Object
        $id:"2"
        Value1:18.44
        GeoName:"WEST"
        Value2:87.89
        Value3:16.73
        Value4:90.71
```

I have tried using

```
Obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyObj, function (GeoName, Value1) {
                return Value1.toFixed ? Number(Value1.toFixed(2)) : Value1;
            }));
```

Which did not work for me.

Is there a way i can achieve this by tweaking the above line of code or is there a better  approach to solve this issue?

**Edit1**(After the approach suggested by wostex)

```
var numKeys = ['ShareValue','ReachValue','DepthValue','WidthValue'];
MyObj=Obj.map(e => Object.assign(e,Object.keys(e).filter(k => numKeys.includes(k)).map(v => Object.assign({[v]: parseFloat(e[v]).toFixed(2)}))))
```

This is How my object is looking like

```
0:Object
       0:Object
        ReachValue:87.88
       1:Object
        DepthValue:16.73
       2:Object
        ShareValue:18.44
       3:Object
        WidthValue:90.71
        $id:"1"
        ShareValue:18.44377295716579
        GeoName:"EAST"
        ReachValue:87.88221970554928
        DepthValue:16.732108234801206
        WidthValue:90.71955219607294
```

**Edit2**

```
Obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BubbleObj));
var numKeys = ['ShareValue','ReachValue','DepthValue','WidthValue'];
            var MyObj=Obj.map(e => Object.assign(e,Object.keys(e).filter(k => numKeys.includes(k)).map(v => Object.assign({[v]: parseFloat(e[v]).toFixed(2)}))))
```

Here Obj has the JSON string from the first line of the question and BubbleObj has the Object which i mentioned as MyObj in the question.

Comment: Just FYI you've got multiple properties in the object with the same name, which is invalid. Only the one which was defined last will be accessible

Comment: Seems like it's working for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5v2dzmhe/. Check the console, your values are rounded.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My bad, they are two objects with different names, i have changed it now.

Comment: well you could just loop over the array and the keys in the objects and not parse it.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr I didn't mean the value of `GeoName`, I mean that you have `Value3` defined twice in each object

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry mate, Its a ctrl-c ,ctrl-v mistake i did while blindly copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is just to use `map` - and as long as your Value1-4 are always called that

```js
var input = [{"$id":"1","GeoName":"EAST","Value2":87.88221970554928,"Value4":90.71955219607294,"Value1":18.44377295716579,"Value3":16.732108234801206},{"$id":"2","GeoName":"WEST","Value2":87.88221970554928,"Value4":90.71955219607294,"Value1":18.44377295716579,"Value3":16.732108234801206}];

var output = input.map(function(e) {
    return {
      $id: e.$id,
      GeoName: e.GeoName,
      Value1: Math.round(e.Value1*100) /100,
      Value2: Math.round(e.Value2*100) /100,
      Value3: Math.round(e.Value3*100) /100,
      Value4: Math.round(e.Value4*100) /100
    }
});

console.log(output);
```

If you dont want to hardcode it, you could look for any key starting `Value` - its a little more complex.

```js
var input = [{"$id":"1","GeoName":"EAST","Value2":87.88221970554928,"Value4":90.71955219607294,"Value1":18.44377295716579,"Value3":16.732108234801206},{"$id":"2","GeoName":"WEST","Value2":87.88221970554928,"Value4":90.71955219607294,"Value1":18.44377295716579,"Value3":16.732108234801206}];

var output = input.map(function(e) {
    return Object.keys(e).reduce(function(p,n){
       if(n.startsWith("Value"))
           p[n] = Math.round(e[n]*100)/100;
       else
           p[n] = e[n];
       return p;
    },{})
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: it throws an error which says input.map is not a function.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr You already knew you had a string - and you must have known you needed to `JSON.parse` your string.

Comment: endwith and starts with arent supported in IE. Any work around that you can suggest?

Comment: @Shekar.gvr mdn typically contains a polyfil for unsupported browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: how can i use polly fill method that is explained in that link for my requirement

Answer (score 1):

BTW you have duplicated keys 'Value3' in your first string, other than that you can do the following:

```js
var j = [{"$id":"1","GeoName":"EAST","ShareValue":87.88221970554928,"ReachValue":90.71955219607294,"DepthValue":18.44377295716579,"WidthValue":16.732108234801206},{"$id":"2","GeoName":"WEST","ShareValue":87.88221970554928,"ReachValue":90.71955219607294,"DepthValue":18.44377295716579,"WidthValue":16.732108234801206}];

// your numeric keys
var numKeys = ['ShareValue','ReachValue','DepthValue','WidthValue'];

var res = j.map(e => Object.assign(e, // rewrite each object
  ...Object.keys(e).filter(k => numKeys.indexOf(k) > -1) // pick keys which include 'Value'
    .map(v => Object.assign({[v]: parseFloat(e[v]).toFixed(2)})) // chop numbers
  ))
  
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Is there an endsWith() method as well? as in real i have values like ShareValue,ReachValue,DepthValue,WidthValue which i converted to Value1,Value2... while posting the question.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr updated for your keys. There's `endsWith` too, but I used `includes` here to make it more universal.

Comment: I have tried using your approach, but the object structure is being tampered. Each of the 4 values are being added as 4 new objects within the main object. Please refer edit1 of in the above post.

Comment: What is `MyObj`? My code works with the first line of your question called `JSON string`, namely the ARRAY of objects. Show your real object then.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, please refer the edit 2 in which i gave you the actual piece of code from my application.

Comment: @Shekar.gvr I don't see the JS object with curly braces or brackets. Make `console.log(JSON.stringify(Obj, null, 2))` and show what it outputs.

Comment: endwith and starts with arent supported in IE. Any work around that you can suggest?

Comment: @Shekar.gvr I've changed my code. You can now explicitly define your fields in `numKeys` array. There's also no more functions unsupported by IE left afaik.